# php var inside javascript

Tags: php, javascript

How can i use this variable inside this?

```
<script language="JavaScript">document.title = "{$row['subject']} - Forum - Terraria 7.6";</script>
```

Tried every way

Comment: My question is why are you declaring the title in javascript anyway?  Surely it should be defined in the <title> tag given that you are assigning it to a server-ide variable.

Answer (score 2):

```
document.title = "<?php echo $row['subject'] ?> - Forum - Terraria 7.6";
```

Answer (score 2):

Wrap it in `<?php` tags:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
document.title = "<?php echo $row['subject']; ?> - Forum - Terraria 7.6";
</script>
```

Also, the `language` attribute is depreciated. Don't use it. Use the `type` instead.

Answer (score 1):

output the var in `<?php ?>` tags

```
<script type="text/javascript">document.title = "<?php echo $row['subject'];  ?> 

- Forum - Terraria 7.6";</script>
```

Comment: `language` is deprecated. Please don't just copy and paste his bad code with minor additions.

Comment: Be really carefull ! The code you post leads to injections. When injecting such a var, you have to escape it. This generally a practice to avoid, so it have to be considered twice at least :D

Comment: the language attribute may be deprecated but it's not the case. It doesn't do any wrong in this case. the question was how to assign PHP variables to javascript variables and I showed how. If you'll be pleased I'll remove the language attribute and add type attribute to get valid xHtml tag but that is not what user asked.

Comment: Downvote's way harsh here. The user asked how to put a PHP variable in JavaScript, and this is an accurate response, modifying _the user's code_ slightly to accommodate his request. It's a learning opportunity, I guess, but there are worse things than just answering the question itself. I'd recommend fixing the script tag to `type="text/javascript"`, but this **does** answer the user's question.