# jQuery is it possible to equal js var to php var

Tags: php, jquery

is it possible to equal js var to php var?

```
<?php $count=0; ?> 
<?php $count++; ?>
```

...

```
<script>var $total = {<?php $count; ?>};</script>
```

soemthing like this

Comment: Need either a short tag or an `echo`, but yes, it would work.

Comment: Wouldn't trying it be the easiest thing?

Comment: possible duplicate of [php var inside javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6238692/php-var-inside-javascript)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<script>
    var total = 5;
    var total2 = <?= $count ?>;
    if( total == total2 ) {
        // IT works!
    }
 </script>
```

Keep in mind that the PHP here is rendered BEFORE the page arrives at the browser (where the javascript will be executed).

EDIT: Also note that in the example you posted, using {} will cause javascript to respect the element as an object instead of a primitive integer, which appears to be what you are aiming for.

Comment: you are comparing, but I think that Mercury wants to pass the value of $count in PHP to the $total in JS.

Comment: Edited to do an assignment instead of an if